# iOS UITabBarController issue

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

Just beginning iOS development and I am getting a crash on creating an UITabBarController with a TableViewController in tab 1 (2nd tab).

Here is my code - AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
diseases = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
        Disease *disease1 = [[Disease alloc] init];
        Disease *disease2 = [[Disease alloc] init];
        Disease *disease3 = [[Disease alloc] init];
        Disease *disease4 = [[Disease alloc] init];
        Disease *disease5 = [[Disease alloc] init];

        disease1.name = @"disease1";
        disease2.name = @"disease2";
        disease3.name = @"disease3";
        disease4.name = @"disease4";
        disease5.name = @"disease5";

        [diseases addObject:disease1];
        [diseases addObject:disease2];
        [diseases addObject:disease3];
        [diseases addObject:disease4];
        [diseases addObject:disease5];


UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = 
[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NormalBiopsy" bundle:nil];
firstViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

DiseaseTableViewController *diseaseTableViewController = [[DiseaseTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DiseaseTableViewController" bundle:nil];
diseaseTableViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];

SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
                                              initWithNibName:@"TestYourSelf" bundle:nil];
secondViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];

ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"About" bundle:nil];
thirdViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:3];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

This leads to a UITabBarController with a blank table in the TableView of the DiseaseTableViewController - because no data populated. 
But if I do

```
diseaseTableViewController.diseases = diseases;
```

the app crashes with:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-                [UINavigationController setDiseases:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

So I tried to add the diseaseTableViewController to the navigationController:

```
diseaseTableViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Which causes:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FirstViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I tried populating the DiseaseTableViewController in that class implementation rather than the AppDelegate but ended with a blank table in the UI again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by leaving the original AppDelegate as is, and populating the data of DiseaseController.diseases in the viewDidLoad() kind of like what @Zhang mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Um, not sure if I understood your question correctly, but basically from my understanding you want to create an application with a tab bar interface and each tab can have its own navigation?

You probably want something like this for the app structure:

```
AppDelegate
|
|
|___ UITabBarController
     |
     |__ UINavigationController1
     |   |
     |   |__ DiseaseController1
     |
     |
     |
     |__ UINavigationController2
     |   |
     |   |__ DiseaseController2
     |
     |
     |
     |__ UINavigationController3
     |   |
     |   |__ DiseaseController3
     |
     |
     |
     |
     |__ UINavigationController4
     |   |
     |   |__ DiseaseController4
     |
     |
     |
     |
     |__ UINavigationController5
         |
         |__ DiseaseController5
```

So following that structure, you would:

1. Create and set your UITabBarController as you root controller for the AppDelegate
2. Create your UINavigationController set them as each tab of your UITabBarController
3. Add the matching DiseaseViewController to each of your UINavigationController

When you're dealing with tables, you need to remember to set the table's data source and delegate.

So which ever DiseaseViewController you create your table in, you need to do something like:

```
myTable.source = self;
myTable.delegate = self;
```

Where self refers to the DiseaseViewController you have created the table in e.g.

```
// psuedocode 
@class Disease1
{
   UITableView myTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView myTable;

@end

// implementation code
@implementation Disease1

-(void)viewDidLoad()
{
    . . .
    myTable.source = self;
    myTable.delegate = self;
    . . .
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you slightly missed the question from my poor explanation! Only the DiseaseTableViewController (has an array of diseases) is on tab 1 (2nd tab) then the rest are different view controllers. So therefore I would have 5 diseases as the entries in the table (does this make sense or can I just do it in the viewDidLoad method of the DiseaseTableViewController or its view?). I already have an UiNavigationController pointing at the DiseasTableViewController but keep getting that selection error